# sendmail from python program

Tags: python, linux, sendmail

In the below code ,the mails that are going from the system are going to a spam folder for the user ,the python code is given below.I suspect that sender from is going as root@.
How to correct this

```
  def sendmail(to,fr,subject,msg):
     sendmail_location = "/usr/sbin/sendmail" # sendmail location
     p = os.popen("%s -t" % sendmail_location, "w")
     p.write("From: %s\n" % fr)
     p.write("Reply-to: %s\n" % fr)
     p.write("To: %s\n" % to)
     p.write("Content-type: text/html\n")
     p.write("Subject: %s\n" % subject)
     p.write("\n") # blank line separating headers from body
     p.write(msg)
     status = p.close()
```

`The mail format received in the`

```
     Delivered-To: harry@8767@gmail.com
     Received: by 19.143.162.8 with SMTP id k6gm828f7tfe;
             Tue, 19 Apr 2011 22:42:17 -0700 (PDT)
     Received: by 10.68.9.168 with SMTP id a5try030f516pbb.481.1303278137028;
             Tue, 19 Apr 2011 22:42:17 -0700 (PDT)
     Return-Path: <root@.>
     Received: from  ([174.1.161.204])
             by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id v4si18etrt0pbr.108.2011.04.19.22.42.15
             (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
             Tue, 19 Apr 2011 22:42:15 -0700 (PDT)
     Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 74.3.161.204 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of root@.) client-ip=74.3.161.204;
     Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=neutral (google.com: 174.1.161.204 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of root@.) smtp.mail=root@.
     Received: (qmail 23122 invoked by uid 0); 19 Apr 2011 22:36:27 -0000
     Date: 19 Apr 2011 22:36:27 -0000
     Message-ID: <2010041954235627.25121.qmail@>
     From: admin@xxxxxx.com
     Subject: hi
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sendmail without password authentication (Python 2.4)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726781/sendmail-without-password-authentication-python-2-4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you use the sendmail binary directly???

Python has a nice **smtplib** module for sending mail through arbitrary mail servers
and an **email** module for composing proper RFC-822 compliant mails.

What you are doing is unlikely recommended.

Comment: email.mime is not available in python 2.4??