# Sendmail without password authentication (Python 2.4)

Tags: python, linux, sendmail

How can I sendmail from Python `2.4` *without* any password authentication?

Comment: Why the hell are you using an ancient python version like 2.4?

Comment: The Python version does not matter. The assumption of the OP is just wrong.

Comment: Check this stack:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55672983/how-to-send-an-email-without-login-to-server-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the smptlib example:

http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html

There is no documentation telling you that authentication would be mandatory.

Authentication is optional.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your mail server to allow unauthenticated relaying from the IP running your python code (e.g. 127.0.0.1 if it's the same system).

However, ensure that you do **not** allow relaying for the world - otherwise your server will be throwing SPAM emails around and get blacklisted for it soon.